# recreate a SQL Server view to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2012, I have a CTE to get to every person his top-level manager.

How can I port this query to MySQL?

```
/*
            Alex(1)
    --------------------
    Jhon(2)          Kevin(3)
------------------------------
Mike(4) Amanda(5)  Tom(6) Jery(7)    
*/

declare @t table(EMPLOYEE_ID Int, MANAGER_ID Int, EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(200))
insert @t values(1,null,'Alex'),(2,1,'Jhon'),(3,1,'Kevin'),
                (4,2,'Mike'),(5,2,'Amanda'),(6,3,'Tom'),
                (7,3,'Jerry'),(8,null,'Sasha'),(9,8,'Jimmy'),(10,9,'Ivy')

--To get top level manager of all given persons
;with cte as
(
    select employee_id, manager_id, 
           employee_name, topmanager_id = NULL
    from @t t 
    where manager_id is not null
    union all
    select cte.employee_id, t.manager_id, 
           t.employee_name, cte.manager_id
    from @t t join cte on t.employee_id = cte.manager_id   
)    
select TopManager_Name = c.employee_name, 
       c.topmanager_id, t.*
from cte c 
inner join @t as t on t.employee_id = c.employee_id
where c.manager_id is null;
```

The output is

```
employee_name   topmanager_id   EMPLOYEE_ID MANAGER_ID  EMPLOYEE_NAME
Sasha   8   10  9   Ivy
Sasha   8   9   8   Jimmy
Alex    1   7   3   Jerry
Alex    1   6   3   Tom
Alex    1   5   2   Amanda
Alex    1   4   2   Mike
Alex    1   3   1   Kevin
Alex    1   2   1   Jhon

*/
```

**A Solution:**

```
select TopManagerName = T1.EMPLOYEE_NAME, TopManager_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , T2.EMPLOYEE_NAME
    from @T T1 inner join @T T2 ON T2.MANAGER_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID
    where T1.MANAGER_ID is null
union
select TopManagerName = T1.EMPLOYEE_NAME, TopManager_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , T2.EMPLOYEE_NAME
    from @T T1 inner join (select TManager_ID = T1.MANAGER_ID, T2.*
    from (select T2.* from @T T1 inner join @T T2 ON T2.MANAGER_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID
    where T1.MANAGER_ID is null) as T1
    inner join @T T2 ON T2.MANAGER_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID) T2 ON T2.TMANAGER_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID
where T1.MANAGER_ID is null
order by EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Isn't that elegant and might work on MySQL - but what if the hierarchy is deeper?

Comment: I love it when the question is not really a question, but "do my task for me".

Comment: You are using a recursive CTE.  MySQL does not support any constructs for traversing tree-like structures.  Your best bet is to include the full hierarchy path in the table itself.

Comment: THX for your replies: So i have to convert it to conventional T-SQL first... i may edit the question to point on this topic.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: i developed a query (combatiple to MySQL) which i can use as a view or to store the hierarchy in a table. Is this your meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have tested the (conventional) query on MySQL, and it works:**

```
Cairo Version: 1.8.10
OS: Linux 2.6.32-55-generic
CPU: 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU         T7200  @ 2.00GHz 1000.000 MHz, 2.0 GB RAM
```

After a few little changes in kind of syntax...

```
use test;

create table Test(EMPLOYEE_ID Int,
MANAGER_ID Int,
EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(200));

insert Test values(1,null,'Alex'),(8,null,'Sasha'),
(2,1,'Jhon'),(3,1,'Kevin'),
(4,2,'Mike'),(5,2,'Amanda'),(6,3,'Tom'),(7,3,'Jerry'),
(9,8,'Jimmy'),(12,4,'Mika'),(13,4,'Samanta'),
(10,9,'Ivy'),(14,13,'Molly'),(15,14,'Tamara'),
(11,10,'Butch');

/*
--To get top level manager of all given persons (conventional)
*/

select T1.EMPLOYEE_NAME as TopManagerName, T1.EMPLOYEE_ID as TopManager_ID, T0.EMPLOYEE_ID, T0.MANAGER_ID , T0.EMPLOYEE_NAME
from Test T0, Test T1, (
    select TL2.EMPLOYEE_ID, TL2.MANAGER_ID 
    from (select Employee_ID, Max(Level) as Level
        from (select T2.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 1 as Level  from Test T1, Test T2 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T3.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 2 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T4.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 3 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3, Test T4 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T5.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 4 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3, Test T4, Test T5 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T6.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 5 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3, Test T4, Test T5, Test T6 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID and T5.EMPLOYEE_ID = T6.MANAGER_ID
            ) as TL
        group by Employee_ID
        ) as TL1 
        , (select T2.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 1 as Level from Test T1, Test T2 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T3.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 2 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID 
            union
            select T4.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 3 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3, Test T4 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T5.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 4 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3, Test T4, Test T5 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T6.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , 5 as Level from Test T1, Test T2, Test T3, Test T4, Test T5, Test T6 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID and T5.EMPLOYEE_ID = T6.MANAGER_ID
        ) as TL2
        where TL2.EMPLOYEE_ID = TL1.EMPLOYEE_ID
        and TL2.Level = TL1.Level
) T2
where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID
and T0.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.EMPLOYEE_ID
order by EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

**The Result:**

```
TopManagerName,TopManager_ID,EMPLOYEE_ID,MANAGER_ID,EMPLOYEE_NAME
Alex,1,2,1,Jhon
Alex,1,3,1,Kevin
Alex,1,4,2,Mike
Alex,1,5,2,Amanda
Alex,1,6,3,Tom
Alex,1,7,3,Jerry
Sasha,8,9,8,Jimmy
Sasha,8,10,9,Ivy
Sasha,8,11,10,Butch
Alex,1,12,4,Mika
Alex,1,13,4,Samanta
Alex,1,14,13,Molly
Alex,1,15,14,Tamara
```

Is there a kind of better solution on MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I have entered some more Hierarchy-levels to test the following draft:

```
declare @t table(EMPLOYEE_ID Int,
MANAGER_ID Int,
EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar(200))
insert @t values(1,null,'Alex'),(8,null,'Sasha'),
(2,1,'Jhon'),(3,1,'Kevin'),
(4,2,'Mike'),(5,2,'Amanda'),(6,3,'Tom'),(7,3,'Jerry'),
(9,8,'Jimmy'),(12,4,'Mika'),(13,4,'Samanta'),
(10,9,'Ivy'),(14,13,'Molly'),(15,14,'Tamara'),
(11,10,'Butch')

--To get top level manager of all given persons
;with cte as
(
    select employee_id, manager_id, employee_name, topmanager_id = NULL
    from @t t where manager_id is not null
    union all
    select cte.employee_id, t.manager_id, t.employee_name, cte.manager_id
    from @t t join cte on t.employee_id = cte.manager_id

)


select TopManager_Name = c.employee_name, c.topmanager_id, t.*
from cte c inner join @t as t on t.employee_id = c.employee_id
where c.manager_id is null
order by EMPLOYEE_ID

/*
--To get top level manager of all given persons (conventional)
*/

select TopManagerName = T1.EMPLOYEE_NAME, TopManager_ID = T1.EMPLOYEE_ID, T0.EMPLOYEE_ID, T0.MANAGER_ID , T0.EMPLOYEE_NAME
from @T T0, @T T1, (
    select TL2.EMPLOYEE_ID, TL2.MANAGER_ID 
    from (select Employee_ID, [Level] = Max([level]) 
        from (select T2.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 1 from @T T1, @T T2 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T3.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 2
            from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T4.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 3 from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3, @T T4 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T5.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 4 from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3, @T T4, @T T5 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T6.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 5 from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3, @T T4, @T T5, @T T6 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID and T5.EMPLOYEE_ID = T6.MANAGER_ID
            ) as TL
        group by Employee_ID
        ) as TL1 
        , (select T2.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 1 from @T T1, @T T2 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T3.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 2 from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID 
            union
            select T4.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 3 from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3, @T T4 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T5.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 4 from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3, @T T4, @T T5 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID
            union
            select T6.EMPLOYEE_ID, T2.MANAGER_ID , [Level] = 5 from @T T1, @T T2, @T T3, @T T4, @T T5, @T T6 where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID and T2.EMPLOYEE_ID = T3.MANAGER_ID and T3.EMPLOYEE_ID = T4.MANAGER_ID and T4.EMPLOYEE_ID = T5.MANAGER_ID and T5.EMPLOYEE_ID = T6.MANAGER_ID
        ) as TL2
        where TL2.EMPLOYEE_ID = TL1.EMPLOYEE_ID
        and TL2.[Level] = TL1.[Level]
) T2
where T1.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.MANAGER_ID
and T0.EMPLOYEE_ID = T2.EMPLOYEE_ID
order by EMPLOYEE_ID
```

This one is much more structured and might be good for some more levels. It rests to test it on MySQL...